# How can I use keystore.jks and truststore.jks files for Kafka Python SSL Authentication after converting to .pem?

Tags: python, ssl, apache-kafka, ssl-certificate, kafka-python

I have 2 certificate files, `truststore.jks` and `keystore.jks`. `keystore.jks` contains a full  certificate chain for the kafka endpoint I'm using as well as a private key for my application. According to the group who gave me `truststore.jks` it contains "a new root CA chain" and is essential for getting my application to connect with the kafka endpoint.

I have tried using this script to generate 3 .pem files that I use in my Python code.

```
#!/bin/bash
srcFolder=$1
keyStore=$1/$2
password=$3
alias=$4
outputFolder=$5

echo $keyStore
echo "Generating certificate.pem"
keytool -exportcert -alias $alias -keystore $keyStore -rfc -file $outputFolder/certificate.pem -storepass $password

echo "Generating key.pem"
keytool -v -importkeystore -srckeystore $keyStore -srcalias $alias -destkeystore $outputFolder/cert_and_key.p12 -deststoretype PKCS12 -storepass $password -srcstorepass $password
openssl pkcs12 -in $outputFolder/cert_and_key.p12 -nodes -nocerts -out $outputFolder/key.pem -passin pass:$password

echo "Generating CARoot.pem"
keytool -exportcert -alias $alias -keystore $keyStore -rfc -file $outputFolder/CARoot.pem -storepass $password
```

I use the generated `CARoot.pem`, `certificate.pem`, and `key.pem` files in my code like so.

```
>>> from kafka import KafkaProducer
>>> producer = KafkaProducer(bootstrap_servers='kafka-dev.kafka.com:port', security_protocol="SSL",
... ssl_check_hostname=True,
... ssl_cafile="CARoot.pem",
... ssl_certfile="certificate.pem",
... ssl_keyfile="key.pem",
... ssl_password="")
```

It gives this error:

```
ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1131)
```

I have tried combining `truststore.jks` and `keystore.jks` like so:

```
keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore truststore.jks -destkeystore keystore_copy.jks
```

I then put `keystore_copy.jks` through the same `.pem` conversion process as before, but it produces the same error.

For some context, this is how the Kafka endpoint owners suggest to configure the ssl certs in Java, unfortunately I am the first to connect with Python so they haven't been able to help me with it.

```
props.setProperty(CommonClientConfigs.SECURITY_PROTOCOL_CONFIG, "SSL");
props.setProperty(SslConfigs.SSL_TRUSTSTORE_LOCATION_CONFIG, "<kafka-truststore.jks>");
props.setProperty(SslConfigs.SSL_TRUSTSTORE_PASSWORD_CONFIG, "<password>");
props.setProperty(SslConfigs.SSL_KEYSTORE_LOCATION_CONFIG, "<client-keystore.jks>");
props.setProperty(SslConfigs.SSL_KEYSTORE_PASSWORD_CONFIG, "<password>");
props.setProperty(SslConfigs.SSL_KEY_PASSWORD_CONFIG, "<password>");
```

Is there something I'm missing? I believe I need to utilize both `.jks` files in my code somehow but the only approach I can think of taking failed.

Additional things I have tried:
`pip install --upgrade certifi` based on reports of the same error due to that library being out of date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to figure out the solution on my own. The key here was realizing that I needed to have the entire cert chain from my `truststore.jks` file present in `CARoot.pem` for the code to work. Here are the steps that I took:

Generate `CARoot.pem` from the trust store:

```
keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore <<truststore-name.jks>> -destkeystore keystore.p12 -srcstoretype jks -deststoretype pkcs12
```

```
openssl pkcs12 -in keystore.p12 -out CARoot.pem
```

Generate `certificate.pem` from keystore

```
keytool -exportcert -alias <<alias>> -keystore ./<<keystore—name.jks>> -rfc -file ./certificate.pem -storepass <<password>>
```

Extract private key and generate `RSAkey.pem` from keystore:

```
keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore <<keystore-name.jks>> -destkeystore keystore.p12 -deststoretype PKCS12
```

```
openssl pkcs12 -in keystore.p12 -nodes -nocerts -out RSAkey.pem
```

Example with Kafka-Python Producer:

```
producer = KafkaProducer(bootstrap_servers='kafka-dev.kafka.com:port', security_protocol="SSL",
ssl_check_hostname=False,
ssl_cafile="CARoot.pem",
ssl_certfile="certificate.pem",
ssl_keyfile="RSAkey.pem",
ssl_password=<<password>>)
```

Comment: In the step - "Generate certificate.pem from keystore", if you don't know the alias, you can use this command to retrieve the alias - `keytool -list -v -keystore <<keystore-name.jks>>`

Answer (score 0):

The following properties which KAFKA endpoint owners are asked you is correct, but looks like the issue with your keystore/truststore having a self signed certificate. It appears ssl.verify or hostName verification is enabled at the server level.

```
props.setProperty(CommonClientConfigs.SECURITY_PROTOCOL_CONFIG, "SSL");
props.setProperty(SslConfigs.SSL_TRUSTSTORE_LOCATION_CONFIG, "<kafka-truststore.jks>");
props.setProperty(SslConfigs.SSL_TRUSTSTORE_PASSWORD_CONFIG, "<password>");
props.setProperty(SslConfigs.SSL_KEYSTORE_LOCATION_CONFIG, "<client-keystore.jks>");
props.setProperty(SslConfigs.SSL_KEYSTORE_PASSWORD_CONFIG, "<password>");
props.setProperty(SslConfigs.SSL_KEY_PASSWORD_CONFIG, "<password>");
```

This is one give you better clarity on this error.

https://community.ibm.com/community/user/ibmz-and-linuxone/blogs/sheng-jie-han/2021/06/03/how-to-fix-certificate-verify-failed-self-signed-c

Comment: None of the proposed solutions in this article worked unfortunately, I can't bypass the SSL verification process and certifi is already up to date. Do I need to perhaps add one of the .jks files to the python CAcert.pem file?